# Is there a known method to track perspective without guidelines, other than experience?

Tags: drawing, linear-perspective

I'm aware of the Brewer method for starters, but other information would be helpful.

Comment: The Brewer method actually creates guidelines, so can you clarify what you mean by "track perspective without guidelines"? Would using string that is attached to a nail count, as with it you can create guidelines while it's not particularly useful for detailed drawing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful(ly inventive) tool called a **centrolinead**, which I still hope to get my hands on one day:

[image: image of centrolinead as it appeared in an ad by Keuffel and Esser Co. New York.]
<sup>[source](https://gurneyjourney.blogspot.com/2010/06/centrolinead.html)</sup>

It consists of a metal joint from which three wooden, rotatable arms extend. You only need two fixed points right next to you drawing on both sides (like thumbtacks or nails). The longer arm acts as if it reaches a vanishing point that is much further away. The two smaller arms can be fastened once you're happy with that vanishing point.

It's also not very hard to craft yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use thread and nail.
You should loose fix the thread on the horizon and with the help of nail to move across the surface to check the perspective.